# Can we not use to be + v3 negatively

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice, do-support, negative-raising

To be + v3

- These clothes are to be washed.
- These clothes are not to be washed.

Likewise,

- These clothes have to be washed.

Now If I have to say it negatively, how can I?

- These clothes have not to be washed.

Is saying it like this correct?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146107/discussion-on-question-by-junaid-can-we-not-use-to-be-v3-negatively); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.